# What exactly are advances in FATE?

Tags: fate, legends-of-anglerre, spirit-of-the-century

I'm looking through my copy of Legends of Anglerre for this, and also searched the Spirit of the Century SRD, and I'm completely stumped as to exactly what an "advance" is. In both instances the terms are used out of the blue without any prior explanation of what they are or any entry in the index, nor is there a glossary of terms (something I'd have never guessed I would miss).

Comment: How about a page reference for context ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SOTC, advances are bonuses to NPC's (Ch5, p78, heading Companions), and are spent when the NPC is created. An advance can...

- Improve quality of companion one step (starts at average)
- Add an additional conflict type the companion can help
- Make them independent
- Give them a skill tree of their own
- Keeping Up - have comparable transport to be able to keep up with a high speed hero
- Communications - secret communications method

LoA uses the same basic mechanics; rules for advances are on page 166-167.

In both, they are defined for companions, but are also used for contacts and some other types of NPC's.

SOTC vehicles have other advances, doing different things, but still are changes made based upon stunts possessed to something other than the character with the stunt.

With the GM's and group's permissions, you might be allowed to leave some unspent, and spend them as certain elements are found to be needed.

Comment: Thanks. That makes things a lot more clear. I'm still unclear though if advances are spent during character creation/when the power is picked or if it's when they're used. I see certain named demons have a really high number of required advances, which would be pretty limiting if you can't allocate them on the fly.

Comment: when created, at least in SOTC. Your companions/mooks/pets/vehicles are part of your character; that is why you spent stunts on them.